# Python Subprocess locks up with High content length

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've written a neovim plugin (not the important part) that uses a python subprocess as background daemon. I send data to stdin and return data from stdout

Basics of the plugin are here

- [Starting the server](https://github.com/mhartington/nvim-typescript/blob/master/rplugin/python3/nvim-typescript/client.py#L54)
- [Sending a request to stdin](https://github.com/mhartington/nvim-typescript/blob/master/rplugin/python3/nvim-typescript/client.py#L87)

As the code is now, everything works as expected. But now I'm seeing the `__server_handle` locks up when the returned content length is quite high, around 33K. [In this while block](https://github.com/mhartington/nvim-typescript/blob/master/rplugin/python3/nvim-typescript/client.py#L116-L129) I'm trying to extract the actual content from stdout, but it cannot return the data, only locking up at the content length.

Is there possibly a better way of handling this so that the subprocess does not get locked up?

```
    while True:
        headerline = Client.__server_handle.stdout.readline().strip()
        linecount += 1

        if len(headerline):
            key, value = headerline.split(":", 2)
            headers[key.strip()] = value.strip()

            if "Content-Length" not in headers:
                raise RuntimeError("Missing 'Content-Length' header")

            contentlength = int(headers["Content-Length"])
            returned_string = Client.__server_handle.stdout.read(contentlength)
            ret = json.loads(returned_string)
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the pipe gets filled up with so much data, that the subprocess gets blocked, while your code is blocked because it's trying to read which leads to a deadlock.

Why not poll the data instead of block reading?

Check out the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/select.html) of `select` for waiting for IO completion.

Comment: By polling, do you mean just "pinging" the process until the data gets returned? My concern is that the data being sent back is for code completion, which is not async